# How can I set the opacity of a geojson object or layer in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm trying to apply `opacity` to a geojson layer in `leaflet.js`.  The [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) seems to show that `opacity` can be set in the style configuration.

```
var exteriorStyle = {
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "weight": 0,
    "opacity": 0.99
};

var exteriorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(exteriorMaskGeojsonPoly, {style: exteriorStyle}).addTo(map);
```

I'd like the object to mask/hide the background map.  Here, using `exteriorStyle`, the color *does* get applied to the resulting `exteriorMaskLayer`, and the polygon is displayed.

However, the `opacity` value appears to be ignored.

I've also tried using the `setOpacity()` method of the `exteriorMaskLayer` with no effect.

```
var exteriorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(exteriorMaskGeojsonPoly, {style: exteriorStyle}).addTo(map);
exteriorMaskLayer.setOpacity(1.0);
```

How can I set the opacity of a geojson object or layer in leaflet?

*using Leaflet-Leaflet-v0.5.1-0-gc1d410f.zip*

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the answer browsing some of the other leaflet documentation.
The style attribute I needed was `fillOpacity`.

I guess `opacity` is only applied to the border.
`weight`, here, turns off the border, so I didn't notice any change.

So this works, applying opacity to the interior of a polygon:

```
var exteriorStyle = {
    "color": "#ffffff",
    "weight": 0,
    "fillOpacity": .75
};

var exteriorMaskLayer = L.geoJson(exteriorMaskGeojsonPoly, {style: exteriorStyle}).addTo(map);
```

I couldn't find any docs on the available style attributes.

Comment: Thank you! Did you ever find any good documentation that goes into the specifics of geojson styling?